# Flutter queue API requests to execute later

Tags: api, flutter, queue, offline-mode, dio

I am implementing an app that I should handle offline mode. When I check the internet connection and it is not connected, I should add the `API` request to a queue to be executed when the internet connection is back again.

How can I do that?

I tried to add class names and the method names to the queue, but couldn't call the method from a class dynamically.

I am using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to handle `API` requests.

Answer (score 2):

if you remove `await` from your requests you can save them as `Future<dynamic>` for Example

```
Future<dynamic> response = Dio().get("http://www.google.com");
```

now You can save it in `List<Future<dynamic>> myList = List()` and when you want to call it

```
await myList[0]
```

Or

```
myList[0].then()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I have Implemented in this way. I know it too late to answer the question but still it will be useful in future.

> FailedOrderQueue.dart
>
> ```
> import 'dart:convert';
>
> import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
> import 'package:select_driver_app/Models/Order.dart';
>
> class FailedOrdersQueue {
>   GetStorage box = new GetStorage();
>   List items = [];
>
>   bool get hasItems {
>     return items.isNotEmpty;
>   }
>
>   bool get isEmpty {
>     return items.length == 0;
>   }
>
>   FailedOrdersQueue() {
>     // removeAll();
>     items = _loadQueue();
>   }
>
>   List _loadQueue() {
>     return box.read('queue') ?? [];
>   }
>
>   bool exists(int orderId) {
>     if (items.isEmpty) {
>       return false;
>     }
>     try {
>       dynamic object = items.firstWhere(
>         (element) => element['order_id'] == orderId,
>       );
>
>       return object == null ? false : true;
>     } catch (e) {
>       return false;
>     }
>   }
>
>   removeAll() {
>     items = [];
>     _commit();
>   }
>
>   add(Order order, int currentTripId) {
>     if (!exists(order.id)) {
>       items.add({
>         'order_id': order.id,
>         'trip_id': currentTripId,
>         'credit_note': jsonEncode(order.creditNoteList),
>         'delivery_img_path': order.image,
>         'sign_img_path': order.signature
>       });
>
>       _commit();
>     }
>   }
>
>   _commit() {
>     box.write('queue', items);
>   }
>
>   remove(Order order) {
>     items.removeWhere(
>       (element) => element['order_id'] == order.id,
>     );
>     _commit();
>   }
>
>   removeById(int id) {
>     items.removeWhere(
>       (element) => element['order_id'] == id,
>     );
>     _commit();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> main.dart or in controller(Getx)
>
> ```
> FailedOrdersQueue failedOrderQueue = new FailedOrdersQueue();
>
> failedOrderQueue.add(order, currentTripId!);
> failedOrderQueue.remove(order);
>
> failedOrderQueue.items.forEach((rawOrderInfo) {
>    //process the queue
> });
> ```

This approach save the data in the Get storage, if you don't want to persist data then you can remove it.